# Change max_input_time when you don't have access to php.ini file

Tags: web-hosting, htaccess, wordpress, php

I am using freehosting website to host my wordpress blog. However, while trying to use duplicator plugin to migrate my blog it asks me to change the **max_input_time** value to **0**

I don't see **php.ini** file in my file manager in cpanel. The next best thing i found is **.htaacess** file

I put the following line at the end of the file however it doesn't seem to work.

```
php_value max_execution_time 300
```

Comment: The file extension might be hidden in your file manager. You should use an FTP or SFTP client to browser the root `public_html` folder, and make sure that the option to show hidden files is enabled in it. See this related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18495524/how-to-access-the-php-ini-from-my-cpanel).

Answer (score 1):

You can only use `.htaccess` to set PHP config options when PHP is installed as an Apache module (although you would ordinarily expect a 500 error if this is not supported). On CGI/FastCGI SAPI you would need to use a per-directory `.user.ini` file:

```
max_execution_time=0
```

However, your host might use a file of a different name, so you may need to ask them.

[`max_execution_time`](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php) can also be set in the script itself using `ini_set()`:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time',0);
```